# Uso correcto de variable Final en java para valor fijo

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy realizando un sistema de tareas, tengo un problema y a la vez duda.
Al ingresar al menú de mis tareas me debe listar las tareas de ese usuario con su ID de esa persona, todo funciona bien pero al ingresar al contenedor de tareas no me muestra las tareas porque la variable final esta en (0) mi código es el siguiente no estoy seguro si la estoy usando de buena manera o como usar una variable que siempre tenga un valor fijo.

Clase CUsuario.

```
public int getID() {
        // Getter envia retorna el id
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        // Setter recibe el id del usuario
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public final int idFinal = ID;
    // Aca la variable final le asigne el valor del ID Getter

    public int getIdFinal() {
        return idFinal;
    }
```

Clase CTareasDAO

```
 public List listareas() {
        List<CTareas> listarea = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            conn = cn.getGonexion();
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tareas WHERE Id_UsDesarrolla = ?");
            ps.setInt(1, us.getIdFinal());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                CTareas tareas = new CTareas();

                tareas.setIdtr(rs.getInt("Tr_Id"));
                tareas.setNombretr(rs.getString("Tr_Nombre"));
                tareas.setCaracteristicastr(rs.getString("Tr_Caracteristicas"));
                tareas.setComentariordir(rs.getString("Tr_ComentariosDir"));
                tareas.setComentarioaux(rs.getString("Tr_ComentariosAux"));
                tareas.setFechainicio(rs.getDate("Tr_FechaInicio"));
                tareas.setFechafinal(rs.getDate("Tr_FechaFinal"));
                tareas.setEstadotr(rs.getInt("Tr_Estado"));
                tareas.setAprobaciontr(rs.getString("Tr_Aprobacion"));
                tareas.setIddesarrolla(rs.getInt("Id_UsDesarrolla"));
                tareas.setIdasigna(rs.getInt("Id_UsAsigna"));

                listarea.add(tareas);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return listarea;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras una variable como final estás indicando que esa variable **no se podrá modificar**, será la misma para todos los objetos creados de esa clase. Esto significa que una vez que has asignado un valor a esa variable el resto de objetos tendrán el mismo valor. Esencialmente esa variable es una constante.

```
 public final int idFinal = ID;   //esta variable tendrá el ID asignado y no cambiará.
```

**Consideraciones** con una variable final:

> Es una recomendación que el nombre de las constantes estén en mayúsculas.
>
> Es recomendable incializar las variables final en el momento de su declaración.
>
> En cualquier caso una variable final solo puede ser inicializada una vez.

**Nota:** No confundir el concepto con **clases** con **final**, una clase declarada como final es una clase que no se puede heredar. Los **métodos** también puede ser finales, estos métodos no pueden ser sobreescritos.

Sobre tu problema, comentas que inicializas la variable idFinal con getID que devuelve un ID. Creo que para este caso lo conveniente sería que tuvieras una variable normal tipo int e inicialices esa variable en el constructor, así cuando crees el objeto se asignará el id como tu quieras.

No se si entendí bien lo que intentas hacer pero te pongo un pequeño ejemplo de como sería el constructor básico:

Ejemplo:

```
    private int idUsuario;
    //el resto de atributos
    
    public CUsuario(aquí van tus atributos, int idUsuario){
       this.idUsuario = idUsuario;  
       //todo, atributos
    }

    public getIdUsuario(){
       return this.idUsuario;
    }
```

He vuelto a leer tu pregunta, deseas mostrar las tareas de un alumno concreto que tiene un ID. No me fijé bien, perdón. Aún que la filosofía es la misma, el ID del usuario no debe de ser final debido a que todos los objetos de la clase CUsuario tendrán el mismo ID. **Si no deseas cambiar nunca el valor del ID no agregues el setter y declara la variable como privada, y solo se podrá definir el ID del usuario en el momento de crear el objeto a través del constructor**.

Comment: Si la variable final la declare como privado y no agregue Set solo deja el Get,
Esta el login valida el usuario y con ese correo trae el ID de ese usuario lo que intento es que ese id se asigne a la variable final:
La variable final debe tener ese id, ya que por el id recargo toda la información del usuario y necesitaría usar ese id en muchos mas formularios web, eso es lo que deseo hacer que jamas se vuelva null la variable

Comment: No se si leíste la respuesta entera, pero no puedes usar final en esa variable de clase ya que entonces esa varía le de vuelve común a la clase. Repásalo otra vez y pruébalo, un saludo.